# Request headers in Django are received only for POST, but not for GET method

Tags: python, django, nginx, header, request

I'm having a weird issue: When sending a GET request with headers from my local machine to our server, I cannot see these headers in the Django backend:

I send the request like so:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://subdomain.example.com/', headers = { 'Host': 'example.com', 'X-Forwarded-Host': 'subdomain.example.com' })
```

In Django, I check for the header like this:

```
if 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST' in request.META:
    # do something
```

It does work properly, though, when making POST requests:

```
import requests
r = requests.post('https://subdomain.example.com/', headers = { 'Host': 'example.com', 'X-Forwarded-Host': 'subdomain.example.com' })
```

The only header that works, is `Host` ... and I'm at the end of my wits :-P The requests are received by an NGINX server using WSGI. Any idea what could coulde POST headers to get passed through, and GET headers to be removed or cleared?

Comment: Are you posting to the same url in both cases?

Comment: Same URL, yes. Yet, I manually set a different Host header in order to mimic a proxy server: `r = requests.get('https://safesearch.pixabay.com/en/photos/', headers = { 'Host': 'pixabay.com', 'X-Forwarded-Host': 'safesearch.pixabay.com' })`

Comment: Please post your nginx config

Comment: I've adapted the OP in order to reflect the real-world situation better. @bruno: It's a very long config. Are there any specific parts, which might be helpful or responsible?

Comment: @SimonSteinberger I'm by no mean an ngnix expert so I can't tell for sure but obviously any part of the config where there's a `proxy_XXX` directive should be included. Alternatively you could (well, you actually _should_) try to build a MCVE reproducing the problem and post it - if you don't find issue by yourself while doing so, which is often the case ;)

Comment: I think, we don't have any `proxy_` directives in the config file. I was hoping it was some known issue that others may have encountered before ... It's a bit difficult to create a MCVE, given that local code, NGINX, and Django is involved. But I'll try to narrow it down. Thanks!